# Prove that for $f(x) = 2x + 1$ defined in the interval $(0,1)$, $f$ has no maximum value

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that for $f(x) = 2x + 1$ defined in the interval $(0,1)$, $f$ has no maximum value.

I have this idea: if we suppose $f$ has maximum, then there exist $x$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f(x) \le f(c)$ and equivalent with $x \le c$. So it contradicts with the fact $(0,1)$ is an open interval.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: "it contradicts with the fact $(0, 1)$ is an open interval" is on the right track, but why? Suppose there is a maximum $f(x)$, can you construct $f(x + c)$ such that $x + c \in (0, 1)$ and $f(x + c) > f(x)$?

Comment: Note that $f$ is increasing!

Comment: It is not about $I=(0,1)$ open, but about $f(I)$ open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the max is achievable at $x = c$, then $f(x) \le f(c)=2c+1$ for all $0 < x < 1$. Note that $0 < c < 1$ as well. So all you need is to find a number $b, 0 < b < 1$ such that $f(b) > 2c+1$, and this means $2b+1 > 2c+1 \implies b > c$. Take $b = \dfrac{1+c}{2}$ would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

$f((0,1)) = (1,3)$ and $(1,3)$ is open hence has no $\max$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for a contradiction a maximum is obtained for $y\in (0,1)$ and also note that $f'(x)> 0$ i.e $f$ is strictly increasing over $(0,1)$. Since $(0,1)$ is an open set, there exists $r>0$ such that $(y-r,y+r)\subset (0,1)$, but then $f\left (y+\frac{r}{2})>f(y\right )$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z\in (0,1) $ then $z < 1$.  By continuity there exist a $y $ so that $z <y <1$ so $y\in (0,1) $.

$z=f (\frac {z-1}2) < y = f (\frac {y-1}2) $.  So $z $ is not a maximal of $f $.  $z $ was arbitrary so no point is a maximal of $f $.